# Why did Voldemort fall with Harry in the final battle?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the finale battle between Harry and Voldemort, Harry leaps off a certain height dragging Voldemort down with him. This causes them both to be disoriented when they land, which ultimately places them on equal ground.

I’m puzzled as to why this super-wizard cannot deflect Harry’s push, or at the most, gain advancement in some manner or another to separate himself away from Harry by means bounding or others. Are there no methods someone of his stature could not employ to simply be saved from the common shove and drag down, despite the surprise of it all? If there are, why could they not be employed? If not- *why not?*

Comment: Because the movie totally made that up... There's no such physical fight in the book.

Comment: They were fighting and Voldemort didn't have time to react, other than to Apparate to the ground

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is, perhaps, precedent for this in the books. In Chapter Seventeen of *Prisoner of Azkaban* we find the following incident:

> He had forgotten about magic — he had forgotten that he was short and skinny and thirteen, whereas Black was a tall, full-grown man — all Harry knew was that he wanted to hurt Black as badly as he could and that he didn’t care how much he got hurt in return —
>
> Perhaps it was the shock of Harry doing something so stupid, but Black didn’t raise the wands in time — one of Harry’s hands fastened over his wasted wrist, forcing the wand tips away; the knuckles of Harry’s other hand collided with the side of Black’s head and they fell, backward, into the wall —

Apparently, a wizard using Muggle fighting techniques against magic is so unexpected that the attacked wizard may not be able to defend himself in time.

Indeed, in Chapter Nineteen of *Order of the Phoenix* when Harry and George physically attacked Malfoy, they received a very serious punishment and it appears that Muggle fighting simply goes against basic wizard norms:

> “But instead of leaving it to Madam Hooch to sort out, you two decided to give an exhibition of Muggle dueling, did you?” bellowed Professor McGonagall. “Have you any idea what you’ve — ?”

Answer (score 3):

The [film screenplay](https://www.scribd.com/doc/163084623/HARRY-POTTER-AND-THE-DEATHLY-HALLOWS-PART-2-by-screenplay-Steve-Kloves) is pretty clear on the order of events. Voldemort is momentarily confused by his failure to kill Harry. Harry takes advantage of this confusion to grab Voldemort and throw them both off of the tower, another unexpected move.

> Voldemort stares at him. Confused. And suddenly, in 
>   this moment, it is Harry, beaten and bloody, who seems in 
>   control. He smiles, then presses even closer, his voice 
>   quiet, vaguely taunting:
>
> **HARRY**: *Come on, Tom. Let’s end this the  way we started it...*
>
> [Harry grabs Voldemort’s cloak in both hands.]
>
> **HARRY**: *Together.*
>
> [And then he falls back, pulling them both...]

If Voldemort was in full possession of his faculties and not fighting someone who can inexplicably block all of his best moves, he would almost certainly have had the capacity to prevent a simple physical attack.